# Duplicating an answer because the question can't be flagged as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, duplicate-answers

I posted an answer on [Spigot 1.18.2 not being recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71678630/10952503). Two weeks later, the OP hadn't accepted the answer, and the answer had a score of zero so the question couldn't be used as a duplicate target.

A new question has since appeared: [Cannot resolve symbol 'JavaPlugin' intelij](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71820658/10952503). It's exactly the same problem, in all regards. As I was not able to flag it as duplicate, I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71825308/10952503) answer. My objective was to wait until one of the answers reaches a score of at least one or gets accepted, then flag the other as duplicate.

Obviously I can't upvote either answer because they're my answers.

Unfortunately, a moderator removed my second answer. I understand that it's a duplicate. But what should be done here?

Comment: Afaik, duplicate closure votes don't require upvoted answers if the target question is asked by the same user

Comment: @Bergi yes but it's not the case here

Comment: Not related to this question, but: I haven't seen you in the review queues for a while; we miss you! I hope you are well.

Comment: @JeremyCaney I'm fine thanks for asking <3. I stop making review at 10k in first answer. Because I didn't have the time, and that was lot of work (except if I was rushing, but also possibly making bad review). I made my part, sometimes I do few review. I'm always world-first in First question and second in First answer x)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You already had a duplicate answer here on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71551704/javaplugin-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type) answered 21 March. You could have flagged both questions as duplicates of this one, and improved your original answer instead.

If you are unable to flag as duplicate of because the original question doesn't have any upvoted/accepted answers, you could do one of the following:

- Find another suitable question to flag/close as duplicate of
- Post an answer/Improve your answer and wait for it to get upvoted/accepted
- Draw attention to the question by starting a bounty
- Flag for moderator attention. In the custom flag, include the link to the original question, and you must also explain that you are unable to flag/vote as duplicate because the original does not have an upvoted/accepted answer.

See also: [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions)

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't remember of this one. I will edit it thanks

Comment: Good advice for this particular case, but I feel like the question does raise a legitimate use case where it's not obvious what we should do and that the principle behind this advice (find an older dupe that is a candidate for target) wouldn't necessarily apply. Your answer would be much better if it spent a few words addressing that as well.

Comment: I notice you edited in the link to the FAQ, but the FAQ still doesn't address the case of the duplicate being unavailable as a target because it lacks any upvoted/accepted answers.

Comment: @jpmc26 done___